# Duda teórica sobre código reentrante C/C++

Tags: c++, c

Me están diciendo que el siguiente código es no reentrante por lo que no es seguro de ejecutar en distintos hilos. Pero no acabo de entender la razón exacta de por que no lo es.

```
VOID EscribeByteAlFinalDelArchivo(LPSTR nArchivo, BYTE c) {
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
HANDLE h1 = CreateFile(nArchivo, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
SetFilePointer(h1, 0, NULL, FILE_END);
EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
WriteFile(h1, &c, 1, NULL, NULL);
LeaveCriticalSection(&cs); CloseHandle(h1);
}
```

Pienso que tal vez es por que en SetFilePointer se está llamando al HANDLE h1 fuera de la sección crítica(?). Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy totalmente seguro, pero creo que tienes razón, el problema de la función es la llamada a `SetFilePointer`, basta con decir que dos hilos pueden cambiar el puntero antes de que el otro escriba el byte al final, es decir que ambos quedarían con el puntero en la misma posición, luego uno de los hilos sobreescribiría el byte escrito antes por el otro hilo. Sucedería algo como esto (con un solo hilo):

```c
void FilePointerEndTest(LPCSTR lpFileName)
{
    HANDLE h1 = CreateFile(lpFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    HANDLE h2 = CreateFile(lpFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    BYTE b1 = 'A', b2 = 'B';

    SetFilePointer(h1, 0L, NULL, FILE_END);
    SetFilePointer(h2, 0L, NULL, FILE_END);

    WriteFile(h1, &b1, 1, NULL, NULL);
    WriteFile(h2, &b2, 1, NULL, NULL);
}
```

El contenido del archivo será `B`.